# How to Create a Simulator Build for test automation in xamarin ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I Want to create .app file that can run in simulator for test automation purpose. I have check by running app in debug mode in simulator but its not creating build in xcode derive data.

Comment: It is within the build artifacts : 
 `YourSolutionName`/`YourProjectName`/bin/iPhoneSimulator/debug/`ProjectName`.app

Comment: got it, thank you! @SushiHangover